# Postgresql - JSON to Array

Tags: python, json, postgresql, flask

I have created this table in my database;

```
query = """CREATE TABLE INGREDIENTS(
        RECIPE_NAME VARCHAR(50) REFERENCES RECIPES(NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        ID SERIAL REFERENCES RECIPES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        DATA JSON NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(RECIPE_NAME,ID))"""
```

And I insert this row;

```
query = """INSERT INTO INGREDIENTS VALUES
    ('Sushi','1','{"ingredients": ["Fish","Rice","Seaweed"], 
    "amounts": ["1","250gr","100gr"]}')"""
```

I want to get ingredients and amounts as an array. I run this query;

```
query = """SELECT DATA->>'ingredients' FROM INGREDIENTS WHERE ID = %s"""
```

But it gives me as write;

```
('["Fish","Rice","Seaweed"]',)
```

What should I do to get the data like an array not one line string with `"s and ['s`? Thank you.

(I am using Python and Flask)

Comment: Instead of getting it from the database this way, you can get the data you want with the dict process.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

coming_database_value = [('{"ingredients": ["Fish","Rice","Seaweed"], "amounts": ["1","250gr","100gr"]}',),]

data = ast.literal_eval(coming_database_value[0][0])

print(data['ingredients'])
```

Output:

```
['Fish', 'Rice', 'Seaweed']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting it correctly from the database, `DATA->>'ingredients'` does return an array from Postgres. The problem is that you are displaying the entire contents of `cur.fetchall()`, which returns a list of tuples.

```
>>>rows = cur.fetchall()
>>>print ( type(rows))
>>>print (rows)

<class 'list'>
[('["Fish","Rice","Seaweed"]',)]
```

If you want the elements, loop through the list and display the element of each tuple at a particular index.

```
>>>for row in rows:
    print ("Ingredients:  ", row[0] )

Ingredients:   ["Fish","Rice","Seaweed"]
```